# What is the energy density on the surface of a polytropic gas sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics

If one solves Einstein's field equations for the metric of polytropic gas sphere, one stets the gas density at the surface to zero. However, such condition describes vacuum where both pressure and energy density are zero. At the star's surface I expect a non-zero energy density due to the presence of gas molecules there. In my understanding the surface of a gaseous star consists of pressure-less gas but not vacuum. Where is my fallacy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is my fallacy?

The “fallacy” is in the choice of matter model. If you want a solution of Einstein equation with a distinct boundary between matter and vacuum then you have to choose matter that allows nonzero density with zero pressure. But *polytropic gas* has equation of state: $$p=K \rho^{1+\frac1n},$$
where $n\ge 1$ is a constant. So as pressure approaches zero density also approaches zero.

An [interior Schwarzschild solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric) is one such example of solution with nonzero energy density at the boundary of the star. The matter here is incompressible fluid.

Comment: That is clear to me. I have just doubts whether the polytropic EOF is a proper model for a gas sphere in GR.  It is not the same as gas in container.  Additionally, for diverging pressure the energy density of polytropic gas is infinite what physically nonsense is. Do you really think that energy density of gas at the boundary to vacuum can be zero?